# how can i make image hide after 5 seconds and change it to text area using HTML and CSS only

Tags: html, css

page 3 => for your birthday, and it will contain an image after 5 sec the content will change to be a textarea with submit button so user can write a kind msg for you, after submit redirect to page for thank user but in the same layout

Comment: I think for that kind of logic you will need to use JavaScript.

Comment: how can i make it using JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick example if this is what you mean.

```
<div class="parent">
<img src="something.png" class="image"/>
</div>
<button class="BTN" > click </button>
```

JavaScript

```
Var BTN = document.querySelector('.BTN')
BTN.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
document.querySelector('.parent').innerHTML
="<textarea class=""/>"
})
```

Add the setInterval() for time.